# cant fetch data from self created sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from database that i have created using class extended to Sqliteopenhelper class and put it onto the listview but i am getting error while using fetch() function from database class in my activity class. please help me out why am getting error in  "cursor = demo1.fetch();" line only.....but when I include the line demo1.adddata() line which is used to add data  in database, the application runs without giving any error....

mainactivity.java

```
   public class mainactivity extends Activity{
    Listview list;
    Cursor cursor;
    database demo1;
    String[] str;
    int count;
    adapterdemo adapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);


    demo1 = new database(getApplicationContext());

  //demo1.adddata();

    cursor = demo1.fetch();



    count = cursor.getCount();
    str = new String[count];

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {   
        str[i] = cursor.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str[i], 3000).show();
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    adapter= new adapterdemo(this, str);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}}

database.java

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
SQLiteDatabase sql;

public database(Context context) {
    super(context, "Template", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query = "Create table smstemp(sms_Template Text)";
    arg0.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void adddata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sql = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("sms_Template", "wait....");


    sql.insert("smstemp", null, cv);



}



public Cursor fetch() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor c = sql.query("smstemp", new String[]{"sms_Template"}, null,null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide the error logs?

Comment: probably getting NPE at Cursor c = sql.query(..)

Comment: sql = this.getReadableDatabase(); move this ling to onCreate().

Comment: @prabhat You can't call `get...Database()` in sqlite helper `onCreate()`.

Comment: @prabhat yes getting NPE at Cursor c = sql.query("smstemp", new String[]{"sms_Template"}, null,null, null, null, null);
but 
sql variable is working with other functions like deleteall() even when i didn't initialized it in there....
Is it because the return type is of cursor of function...

Comment: please show complete code. i think sql variable would have initialize before call to deleteall() funtion

Comment: yess....I got it...it gets initialized before call to deleteall() func. 
thanks a lot for help...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `sql` is not initialized and hence you get NPE.

Why adding `adddata()` "solves" the problem is because that method initializes the variable.

It's better not to have a `SQLiteDatabase` as a member variable. Instead, initialize a local variable in `fetch()`, like

```
SQLiteDatabase sql = getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Same basic answer as mine, but your explained it better;) Upvote.

Comment: Thankyou @laalto this thing helped...:)

Answer (score 1):

prabhat is right.  I was just writing up a big doc about best practices.  Unnecessary field state is bad.  You don't need:

SQLiteDatabase sql;

Just call getReadableDatabase() in both methods.

Right here is a classic example of why local fields can be bad.

If its a performance thing, the extra method call is like 1/10000000000 of what the actual disk access is going to be.